# How to merge branch in git using `their` when in conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict, merge-strategy

I have a `master` branch for production and a `qa` branch for testing.

When I develop a new feature I create a new branch from master (e.g. new_branch), use it for develop and merge it to qa for testing.

I use the following git alias:

`myc = "!f() { git commit -a -m ${1} && git checkout qa && git merge ${1} && git push origin qa && git checkout ${1}; }; f"`

This strategy allows me to merge into master only features that where approved by QA team.

---

In my code I have a `define.inc.php` where I set a `define('_STATIC_VER_', '20');` this counter is auto-appended to all static css, js files, e.g.:

`/themes/css/global.css?sv=20`

So that when ever I change the css files, I increase the SV counter, therefor forcing the browser to reload all static files.

The problem is - when I have 2 branches in development n1, n2, and both made changes to `define.inc.php` I get

`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in config/defines.inc.php`

and I have to manually choose `their` version of `define.inc.php'

How can I improve my alias command to always use `their` when in conflict?

NOTE: `git merge --strategy-option theirs` doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git merge -s recursive -X theirs` should do the trick.

It'll always take the "incoming" branch changes *when there's a conflict* but behave as a classic merge for all other cases

The full alias cmd is:

`myc = "!f() { git commit -a -m ${1} && git checkout qa && git merge -s recursive -X theirs ${1} && git push origin qa && git checkout ${1}; }; f"`